# How to disable a auto exec in csgo

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I want to disable my auto exec as it irritates me...like it makes the valve intro blurry...when I buy something,the sides of the circle gets blurry

This is the auto exec:-

```
gameinstructor_enable "0" 
cl_showhelp "0" 
cl_autohelp "0" 
cl_disablefreezecam "1" 
cl_disablehtmlmotd "1" 

rate "128000" 
cl_cmdrate "128" 
cl_updaterate "128" 
cl_interp_ratio "1" 
cl_interp "0" 
cl_lagcompensation "1" 
cl_predict "1" 
cl_predictweapons "1"


mat_monitorgamma "1.6" 
mat_monitorgamma_tv_enabled "1" 

fps_max_menu "144" //
fps_max "0" 


r_drawtracers_firstperson "0" 
cl_use_opens_buy_menu "0" 
mm_dedicated_search_maxping "50" 

m_rawinput "1" 
m_mouseaccel2 "0" 
m_mouseaccel1 "0" 
m_customaccel "0" 

r_dynamic "0"
r_eyegloss "0"
r_eyemove "0"
muzzleflash_light "0"
func_break_max_pieces 0
host_writeconfig

l_forcepreload "1"
cl_autowepswitch "0"
cl_disablefreezecam "1"
cl_showhelp 0
cl_autohelp "0"
gameinstructor_enable "0"
```

The picture quality of the game is lighter. I deleted the game and reinstalled it but still it didn't work

Comment: remove `exec autoexec` from the `config.cfg` or just empty/rename the file.

Comment: On a side note, how do you know that autoexec is causing those problems?

Comment: I don't see anything on that file related to visual bugs. Why don't you firstly *check game files*?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the file or rename it, that's the easiest and fastest way.